# Pass motionEvent from one scrollView to another

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a tricky situation here. I have two scrollviews one below the other. As expected the one on top gets the events. What I want to achieve is that when the one on top reaches the end, I want to pass the event to the underlying scrollview in one smooth transition. What I tried is this:

```
    scrollview1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (enable) {

                return scrollview2.onTouchEvent(event);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

But is doesn't seem to work and gives pointer out of range exception.

```
    05-16 16:10:22.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-16 16:10:22.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22038): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:        pointerIndex out of range
    05-16 16:10:22.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22038):    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
    05-16 16:10:22.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22038):    at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:2090)
    05-16 16:10:22.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22038):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:848)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `scrollview2.dispatchTouchEvent(event)` instead